Strange redirect after adding ssl to server
I have a server on which a domain site, lets call it lauraswork.co.uk, I recently moved servers and as part of the move addded an ssl to the server. If I go directly to https://lauraswork.co.uk then the site loads perfectly. If I go to http://lauraswork.co.uk, then for some reason I get redirected to lauraswork.mytestsubdomain.co.uk and an ssl error is thrown.
Here is the *:80 vhost,
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName lauraswork.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.lauraswork.co.uk

        ServerAdmin simon@email.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lauraswork.co.uk/public_html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =lauraswork.co.uk [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.lauraswork.co.uk
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Here is the *:443 vhost
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName lauraswork.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.lauraswork.co.uk

        ServerAdmin simon@myemail.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lauraswork.co.uk/public_html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lauraswork.co.uk/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lauraswork.co.uk/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

Not that is should make any difference but the site is wordpress but there is no reference to lauraswork.mytestsubdomain.co.uk anywhere in the db.

There is nothing in the shown configuration which causes this request. So either it is outside the configuration you show or it is some cached permanent redirect from previous experiments. In the latter case retry with a clean browser profile, i.e. all caches cleared (or just use a new incognito window).

Check your .htaccess file. Within it, locate the 303 rule it will likely point to your "lauraswork.mytestsubdomain.co.uk"

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
